# Eclipse 4.6.1 JGit/EGit lo longer authenticating after upgrade

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit

On Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Anniversary Edition I had a fresh Eclipse 4.6 installed from the Zip file (not from the installer). The upgrade functionality said that 4.6.1 was available and it upgraded. Now when I try to access a Git remote repository (using HTTPS) it asks for my username and password (which it already had). I enter the correct information and it gives me a `401 Unauthorized`.

One of the log messages was "Saved passwords are not available for migration to secure storage. Deprecated authorization classes (org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth) are not installed." I don't know what that means or if it is relevant.

I noticed that Eclipse 4.6.1 created that stupid `RemoteSystemsTempFiles` directory in my projects folder, even though I had turned off "RSE UI" in "Startup and Shutdown" in the settings. I deleted that folder, as I had before with Eclipse 4.6.0. I turned that setting back on later so it would regenerate the stupid folder, but it still doesn't work.

I can `git pull` etc. just fine using the Git command-line client version 2.10.0.windows.1. TortoiseGit also works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are running into a [recently discovered bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000) in Neon.1 (aka 4.6.1). The discussion in that bug gets pretty technical and in the weeds, but several options are being discussed to remedy the problem (see [this message](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/technology-pmc/msg07769.html)). One of which is to update just the MPC portion using a new update site - that's something any user can do himself without waiting for the Eclipse projects to decide on a "global" remedy.

Comment: This is an incredibly huge breakage. Basically upgrading to Neon .1 breaks Git with remote repositories. Lovely. It's not as if anyone uses Git with remote repositories on Eclipse... And these people are still going round and round about the details of how to patch it. If something this big breaks, they should immediately release a Neon .2 within 24-48 hours.

Comment: So this is interesting: if I dismiss the first dialog (apparently the erroneous MPC dialog), I get what apparently is the real EGit dialog and I can enter username and password there, and even ask it to be stored in secure storage. Thereafter I only need to dismiss the first dialog each time and things seem to work as normal.

Comment: If only the situation were as simple as we want it to be. The sim-rel packages and repositories are an incredibly complex system and the people involved are trying to do the best thing for the product and user community as a whole. I would like it if they moved a little faster but being a former developer in that world I understand the complexities maybe more than the average user, so I'm maybe a little more patient.

Comment: By the way, the fix is available on the MPC update site given at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000#c10 . Install that and you should be good to go

Comment: Oh, and my understanding is that this bug only affects accessing git repositories over HTTPS. If you use git protocol or HTTP you'll avoid it.

Comment: The bug has been closed, with the [comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000#c54): "The problematic change was rolled back, and currently there are no plans to revisit the authenticator dialog story."